# How can I asynchronously schedule tasks without asyncio.sleep()?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, python-asyncio

Is there a vanilla way to asynchronously schedule these two tasks? Should this be written a different way? asyncio.sleep(0) works, but I don't want to sleep there.

```
import asyncio

async def skip(name, init, by):
    value = init
    for i in range(10):
        value = value + by
        print(f'{name}: {value}')
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        skip("Odd", -1, 2), 
        skip("Even", 0, 2)
    )

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You **must** call `await` in order to yield control to other async tasks. If you're not doing anything else that's `await`-able, then `asyncio.sleep()` is your best option.

Comment: Are you just interested in seeing the outputs interlaced? Because you can schedule your functions without any await statement, but they won't be interlaced because they wouldn't be awaiting on anything internally. The trick is, you have to identify a good place in your function where waiting would accomplish/benefit you.

Comment: There is no `async` work in your `skip` function, if the function is fast do it `def`, rather than `async def`, if it is CPU heavy move in to the child process using `run_in_executor` with `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with what you're doing, but you should ask what you want to accomplish with your async functions. For example, if you just want to  see them interlaced what you've done is fine, but the main use of async is to allow useful work to occur while a part of your program is waiting on something (be it another part of your program or network IO or other).

If you want to synchronize two coroutines/tasks, which is similar what you've done here but more explicit, you should look into the [asyncio synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio-sync).

**To assuage that what you're doing is acceptable,** [even the `asyncio` lib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4ec9ed8fde8e285a3eea97c199f7bbf7c95c8881/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L354-L377) uses your construction:

```py
    async def drain(self):
        """Flush the write buffer.

        The intended use is to write

          w.write(data)
          await w.drain()
        """
        if self._reader is not None:
            exc = self._reader.exception()
            if exc is not None:
                raise exc
        if self._transport.is_closing():
            # Wait for protocol.connection_lost() call
            # Raise connection closing error if any,
            # ConnectionResetError otherwise
            # Yield to the event loop so connection_lost() may be
            # called.  Without this, _drain_helper() would return
            # immediately, and code that calls
            #     write(...); await drain()
            # in a loop would never call connection_lost(), so it
            # would not see an error when the socket is closed.
            await sleep(0)
        await self._protocol._drain_helper()
```